# Problem using Riverpod Code Generation in Dart (addListener)

Tags: flutter, dart, listener, riverpod, flutter-go-router

I am doing a project with riverpod with annotations after I did the same project without annotations. I have tried to adapt all the providers that I have in the first project, but I am having a problem when accessing the _authNotifier.addListener since it tells me that it is not defined.

I'm not sure what is going on, so it will be helpful y you can help me!

## This is my first project's code and it works perfect

`**auth_provider.dart**`

```dart
final authProvider = StateNotifierProvider<AuthNotifier, AuthState>((ref) {
  final authRepository = AuthRepositoryImpl();
  final keyValueStorageService = KeyValueStorageServiceImpl();

  return AuthNotifier(
    authRepository: authRepository,
    keyValueStorageService: keyValueStorageService,
  );
});

class AuthNotifier extends StateNotifier<AuthState> {
  final AuthRepository authRepository;
  final KeyValueStorageService keyValueStorageService;

  AuthNotifier({
    required this.authRepository,
    required this.keyValueStorageService,
  }) : super(AuthState()) {
    checkAuthStatus();
  }

  Future<void> loginUser(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      final user = await authRepository.login(email, password);
      _setLoggedUser(user);
    } on CustomError catch (e) {
      logout(e.message);
    } catch (e) {
      logout('Error no controlado');
    }
  }

  void registerUser(String email, String password, String fullName) async {}

  void checkAuthStatus() async {
    final token = await keyValueStorageService.getKeyValue<String>('token');
    if (token == null) return logout();

    try {
      final user = await authRepository.checkAuthStatus(token);
      _setLoggedUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      logout();
    }
  }

  _setLoggedUser(User user) async {
    await keyValueStorageService.setKeyValue('token', user.token);

    state = state.copyWith(
      user: user,
      authStatus: AuthStatus.authenticated,
      errorMessage: '',
    );
  }

  Future<void> logout([String? errorMessage]) async {
    await keyValueStorageService.removeKey('token');

    state = state.copyWith(
      authStatus: AuthStatus.unauthenticated,
      user: null,
      errorMessage: errorMessage,
    );
  }
}

enum AuthStatus { checking, authenticated, unauthenticated }

class AuthState {
  final AuthStatus authStatus;
  final User? user;
  final String errorMessage;

  AuthState({
    this.authStatus = AuthStatus.checking,
    this.user,
    this.errorMessage = '',
  });

  AuthState copyWith({
    AuthStatus? authStatus,
    User? user,
    String? errorMessage,
  }) =>
      AuthState(
        authStatus: authStatus ?? this.authStatus,
        user: user ?? this.user,
        errorMessage: errorMessage ?? this.errorMessage,
      );
}
```

`**app_router_notifier.dart**`

```dart
final goRouterNotifierProvider = Provider((ref) {
  final authNotifier = ref.read(authProvider.notifier);
  return GoRouterNotifier(authNotifier);
});

class GoRouterNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  final AuthNotifier _authNotifier;

  AuthStatus _authStatus = AuthStatus.checking;

  GoRouterNotifier(this._authNotifier) {
    _authNotifier.addListener((state) {
      authStatus = state.authStatus;
    });
  }

  AuthStatus get authStatus => _authStatus;

  set authStatus(AuthStatus value) {
    _authStatus = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

## Now this is my second project using annotations (Here is the problem)

`**auth_provider.dart**`

```dart
part 'auth_provider.g.dart';

@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
class Auth extends _$Auth {
  final authRepository = AuthRepositoryImpl();
  final keyValueStorageService = KeyValueStorageServiceImpl();

  @override
  AuthState build() {
    checkAuthStatus();
    return AuthState();
  } 

  Future<void> loginUser(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      final user = await authRepository.login(email, password);

      _setLoggedUser(user);
    } on CustomError catch (e) {
      logout(e.message);
    } catch (e) {
      logout('Error no controlado');
    }
  }

  void registerUser(String email, String password, String username) async {}

  void checkAuthStatus() async {
    final token = await keyValueStorageService.getKeyValue<String>('token');
    if (token == null) return logout();

    try {
      final user = await authRepository.checkAuthStatus(token);
      _setLoggedUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      logout();
    }
  }

  _setLoggedUser(User user) async {
    await keyValueStorageService.setKeyValue('token', user.token);

    state = state.copyWith(
      user: user,
      authStatus: AuthStatus.authenticated,
      errorMessage: '',
    );
  }

  Future<void> logout([String? errorMessage]) async {
    await keyValueStorageService.removeKey('token');

    state = state.copyWith(
      authStatus: AuthStatus.unauthenticated,
      user: null,
      errorMessage: errorMessage,
    );
  }
}

enum AuthStatus { checking, authenticated, unauthenticated }

class AuthState {
  final AuthStatus authStatus;
  final User? user;
  final String errorMessage;

  AuthState({
    this.authStatus = AuthStatus.checking,
    this.user,
    this.errorMessage = '',
  });

  AuthState copyWith({
    AuthStatus? authStatus,
    User? user,
    String? errorMessage,
  }) =>
      AuthState(
        authStatus: authStatus ?? this.authStatus,
        user: user ?? this.user,
        errorMessage: errorMessage ?? this.errorMessage,
      );
}
```

`**app_router_notifier.dart**`

```dart
part 'app_router_notifier.g.dart';

@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
GoRouterNotifier goRouterNotifier(Ref ref) {
  final authNotifier = ref.read(authProvider.notifier);

  return GoRouterNotifier(authNotifier);
}

class GoRouterNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Auth _authNotifier;

  AuthStatus _authStatus = AuthStatus.checking;

  GoRouterNotifier(this._authNotifier) {
   _authNotifier.addListener((state) {
      authStatus = state.authStatus;
    });
  }

  AuthStatus get authStatus => _authStatus;

  set authStatus(AuthStatus value) {
    _authStatus = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

## So what is the problem?

As you can see I'm trying to do the exact same thing, but in `app_router_notifier.dart` in this line:

```dart
_authNotifier.addListener((state) {
      authStatus = state.authStatus;
    });
```

**I'm getting this error:** The method 'addListener' isn't defined for the type 'Auth'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'addListener'.

I've tried different solutions even with AI and nothing. I think that there's something wrong in my auth_provider.dart but I'm not sure what it is. I believe that the `.addListener` is in the `StateNotifier` but it isn't in the NotifierProvider that generates Riverpod.

```dart
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'auth_provider.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// RiverpodGenerator
// **************************************************************************

String _$authHash() => r'baf96bdb5085978702d0e2b04c3a2e56893b8a41';

/// See also [Auth].
@ProviderFor(Auth)
final authProvider = NotifierProvider<Auth, AuthState>.internal(
  Auth.new,
  name: r'authProvider',
  debugGetCreateSourceHash:
      const bool.fromEnvironment('dart.vm.product') ? null : _$authHash,
  dependencies: null,
  allTransitiveDependencies: null,
);

typedef _$Auth = Notifier<AuthState>;
// ignore_for_file: type=lint
// ignore_for_file: subtype_of_sealed_class, invalid_use_of_internal_member, invalid_use_of_visible_for_testing_member, inference_failure_on_uninitialized_variable, inference_failure_on_function_return_type, inference_failure_on_untyped_parameter
```

There are other "solutions" that didn't work for me:

```dart
_authNotifier.listen<AuthStatus>((state) {
      authStatus = state.authStatus;
    });
```

```dart
_authNotifier.ref.listen(authProvider.notifier, (_, currentState) {
      authStatus = currentState.state.authStatus;
    });
```

```dart
 _authNotifier.addListener((state) {
      final authState = _authNotifier.build();
      authStatus = authState.authStatus;
    });
```

## A little bit of context of the application

I'm using Flutter, Dart, Riverpod and Go Router to do a login and signup in my backend (NestJS + GraphQL), in the following file I'm trying to redirect the user if doesn't have a valid token. Here is where I'm using the goRouterNotifier so it can listen when the state changes and redirect the user.

```dart
part 'app_router.g.dart';

@Riverpod(keepAlive: false)
GoRouter goRouter(GoRouterRef ref) {
  final goRouterNotifier = ref.read(goRouterNotifierProvider);

  return GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/login',
    refreshListenable: goRouterNotifier,
    routes: [
      //* First Route
      GoRoute(
        path: '/checking',
        builder: (context, state) => const CheckAuthStatusScreen(),
      ),

      //* Shared Routes
      GoRoute(
          path: '/main/:page',
          builder: (context, state) {
            final pageIndex = state.pathParameters['page'] ?? '0';
            return MainScreen(pageIndex: int.parse(pageIndex));
          }),

      GoRoute(
        path: '/settings',
        builder: (context, state) => const SettingdScreen(),
      ),

      //* Auth Routes
      GoRoute(
        path: '/login',
        builder: (context, state) => const LoginScreen(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/signup',
        builder: (context, state) => const SignUpScreen(),
      ),

      //* Home Routes
    ],
    redirect: (context, state) {
      // print(state.matchedLocation);
      final isGoingTo = state.matchedLocation;
      final authStatus = goRouterNotifier.authStatus;

      if (isGoingTo == '/checking' && authStatus == AuthStatus.checking) {
        return null;
      }

      if (authStatus == AuthStatus.unauthenticated) {
        if (isGoingTo == '/login' || isGoingTo == '/signup') return null;

        return '/login';
      }

      if (authStatus == AuthStatus.authenticated) {
        if (isGoingTo == '/login' ||
            isGoingTo == '/signup' ||
            isGoingTo == '/checking') return '/main/0';
      }

      return null;
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, `StateNotifier` properties such as `.stream` or `.addListener` are not present in `Notifier`. So you should listen to `Notifier` like this:

```dart
_authNotifier.ref.listenSelf((AuthState? previous, AuthState next) {
      authStatus = next.authStatus;
    });
```

or use the `ref.listen` method (**I think this option is the most optimal in this situation**):

```dart
ref.listen(_authNotifier, (AuthState? previous, AuthState next) {
      authStatus = next.authStatus;
    });
```

You can pass `ref` to it through the constructor of the `GoRouterNotifier` class.

In any other cases where you don't have access to `ref`, get the current container from the context (`ProviderScope.containerOf(context)`) and use `providerContainer.listen(provider)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciated, it works fine now. Just a little clarification for others that can be looking for resolve this issue. When I use `ref.listen` it throws an error: **The argument type 'Auth' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AlwaysAliveProviderListenable<AuthState>'**. So what I did was instead of using `_authNotifier` I use directly the provider `authProvider`.